# Regex somestring.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/);

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be the effect of the following line

`somestring.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/);`

in javascript??

I thought it would split at comas with any number of spaces before or after.

But from what i have learned the regex would be like

```
\\s*,\\s*
```

.I am confused

Comment: You'd only use `\\s*` if you use it as a string (`.split(new RegExp('\\s*'))`), but if you create a regex (`.split(/\s*/)`) you don't need to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought it would split at comas with any number of spaces before or after.

That is correct. It will even match commas with *no* spaces before and after.

The `/` before and after is just a syntax that some regex parsers uses as a delimiter for the regex expression.

In Javascript you should use `split('string')` (apostrophes) for splitting on strings or characters, and `split(/regexp/)` (slashes) for splitting on regex expressions.

The double backslash (`\\`) is used to escape special characters in strings so that e.g. `'\n'` is interpreted as a single *line-feed* character while `'\\n'` is interpreted as a backslash and an "n" (`'\n'`).

When using the regex delimiters `/` on your expression, you don't have to escape special characters as the parser knows it's a regex.

```
split(/\s*,\s*/) // No escaping needed with backslash delimiters.
```

Comment: so both expressions are the same , but depending on the parser one might or might not work ??

Comment: @MithunMadhav Your question was badly formatted. `\\s*` would match a backspace (`\\ `) followed by 0 to an infinite amount of `s` characters (eg `\\sssssssssssssssssss`). `\s*` would match 0 to an infinite amount of white space characters (eg. `\n\t\t\t\n\r    \r`)

Comment: @MithunMadhav Yes. In Javascript I think you should use the delimiters to signify that the expression is a regex and not a simple string match.

Comment: FYI: `.split(\s*,\s*)` (no delimiters) would not work. It'd be invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
I thought it would split at comas with any number of spaces before or after to the comas.
```

**So here is example:**

```
'so me          ,                    s t r i n g'.trim().split(",");
```

I Am using `just trim` with `coma` here it `divide the string into two parts` but the first element `contains space at the end`. And the second element contains `space at Begin`.

**Result will be**

```
["so me          ", "                    s t r i n g"]
```

**For Above expression**

```
'so me       ,                s t r i n g'.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/);
```

I Am using `trim with (/\s*,\s*/)`; Here It `divide the string into two parts` but `no space` at `starting of second element and ending of first element`.

Result is

```
["so me", "s t r i n g"]
```